# Egienvalues of a product of symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\boldsymbol\Gamma$ and $\boldsymbol W$ be two real $K\times K$ matrices defined as

$$
\boldsymbol\Gamma= \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{1}{\gamma_1}& 0 & ...&0\\
& & \\
0&\frac{1}{\gamma_2}& ...&0\\
& & \\
\vdots & & & \vdots\\
& & \\
0 & 0 & ... & \frac{1}{\gamma_K}\\
\end{array}
\right),\quad
\mathbf{W}= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\,w_{i,1}\,w_{i,1} &... & \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\,w_{i,1}\,w_{i,K} \\
 & & \\
\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\,w_{i,2}\,w_{i,1} & ... & \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\,w_{i,2}\,w_{i,K} \\
& & \\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
& & \\
\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\,w_{i,K}\,w_{i,1} & ... & \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\,w_{i,K}\,w_{i,K} \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$

with $\gamma_k>0$, $\lambda_i>0$ and $w_{i,k}$ the entries of a $N\times K$ matrix. It is assumed that $w_{i,k}\in[0,1]$. Hence $\boldsymbol W$ can be written as

$$\boldsymbol W=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_i \textbf{w}_i\otimes\textbf{w}_i,$$

where $\textbf{w}_i$  is the vector whose $k$-th element is $w_{i,k}$. What can be said about the eigenvalues of the matrix $\mathbf{\Phi}\equiv\boldsymbol\Gamma\,\textbf{W}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be the $N\times K$ matrix $(w_{ik})$ and $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_N)$. Then $\mathbf{W}=\Omega^\top\Lambda\Omega$ and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ is similar to $\mathbf{\Gamma}^{1/2}\Omega^\top\Lambda\Omega\mathbf{\Gamma}^{1/2}$. Hence all eigenvalues of $\mathbf{\Phi}$ are nonnegative and the number of positive eigenvalues is equal to $\operatorname{rank}(\Omega)$.